# Scrolling beyond the top (and bottom) of a UITableView - so tableview can act like a Picker

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I need to implement something like a picker - with the selector window in the center of a scrolling list of items. It needs to be as tall as the entire screen (but not as wide). Customizing a Picker appeared to be pretty difficult or impossible so I went the route of a UITableView.

It all looks and works fine, except I can't scroll the tableview beyond the top or bottom to get the first or last couple of items under the selector window.

The question essentially is, Is there a way to allow a UITableView to scroll beyond the top or bottom of the list of items?

Here is some debugging output generated by dragging the list so that the first item is under the selector window:

> 2012-11-02 10:28:55.426 testProject[23288:707] itemPicker scrolled to
>   0.000000, -297.000000

Of course it snaps back to:

> 2012-11-02 10:31:04.085 testProject[23288:707] itemPicker scrolled to
>   0.000000, -0.000000

as soon as I let it go. I need for it not to snap back. I've tried numerous variations on adjusting the tableview's content offset, bounces and scrollsToTop with no joy.

Hopefully this question is more clear [than this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077926/scroll-scrollview-like-a-picker) which appeared to be asking the same thing. Please let me know if my question is unclear and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Can you do it by adding empty items at the top and bottom of the table and adjusting your row offsets when populating your cells?

Comment: I would have an `NSArray` of objects to display in the `UITableView`. When the `indexPath` for drawing a cell got close to the top/bottom of my array, I'd repopulate the array with a new range of items and `reloadData` on the `tableview`. As mentioned above, your top/bottom could be empty rows.